# Обратная связь

Tags: связь, html

Добрый день.Скачал на понравившемся сайте исходники страницы.
Так вот теперь не знаю как в форму которая есть прицепить обработчик, который направит данные формы на мой почтовый адрес.Надеюсь выражаюсь понятно...если даже не правильно:)
форма выглядит так:

```
<form method="post" name="feedback">

                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span6">

                        <input type="text" class="put name" name="user_name" data-holder="NAME">

                    </div>

                    <div class="span6">

                        <input type="text" class="put phone" name="user_phone" data-holder="PHONE NUMBER">

                    </div>

                </div>

                <center>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn2" value="CLICK ME" return feed.submit(this);">

                </center>

                <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="ACTION">

            </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@mail.ru"
```

Comment: Инпут ClickMe не активен....

Comment: Может я не прав, но мне по всей видимости нужен action="mail.php", вернее код к нему

Comment: >Инпут ClickMe не активен

ну так сделайте его активным. Иначе зачем он вообще нужен?

Comment: Сделаю...без проблем. А как?))

Comment: @Не_бывалый вообще если этот код вы откуда-то скопировали, и показали его целиком, то никаких проблем с активностью кнопки быть не [должно.Вот например][1]

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/pejQW/